# Only show log in error messages if correct credentials are provided

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've noticed that the default membership system will show log in error messages (for example a locked or disabled account) even if an incorrect password is provided for a valid user. Is there a way to show log in errors  only when both a correct username and password are provided?

```
Protected Sub LoginUser_LoginError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoginError

    LoginUser.FailureText = "Invalid Username or Password - Please Try Again"

    Dim UserName As TextBox = DirectCast(LoginUser.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
    Dim Password As TextBox = DirectCast(LoginUser.FindControl("Password"), TextBox)

    Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName)
    Dim correctCred As Boolean = (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))

    If (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) Then

        If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) & (correctCred = True) Then

            Dim lastLockout As DateTime = CurrentUser.LastLockoutDate
            Dim unlockDate As DateTime = lastLockout.AddMinutes(Membership.PasswordAttemptWindow).AddSeconds(-1)
            Dim unlockCounterMinutes As String = unlockDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Minutes + 1
            Dim unlockCounterSeconds As String = unlockDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Seconds

            If (unlockCounterMinutes > 1) & (correctCred = True) Then
                LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been locked - Please try again in " & unlockCounterMinutes & " Minutes"
            ElseIf (unlockCounterSeconds > 1) & (correctCred = True) Then
                LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been locked - Please try again in " & unlockCounterSeconds & " Seconds"
            Else
                LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account is now being unlocked - Please login again"
            End If

        ElseIf (CurrentUser.IsApproved = False) & (correctCred = True) Then

            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account is disabled - Contact the system administrator"

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know where this current code is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try to separate this line of code

if (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) & (correctCred = True) then

to

```
 if (correctCred = True) then  
      if (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) then   
  '.....your code....  
  '.....your code.... 

       else  
   '...your message when correct credentials and locked account...  
       end if
else  
 '... your error message for wrong credentials.. ..   
end if
```